# Magenta Performance RNN Demo with own MIDI Data

Tags: tensorflow, model, tensorflow.js, magenta

thanks so much for all your efforts bringing magenta closer to artistic dudes like me.

I'm currently trying to port the performance_rnn browser model (https://magenta.tensorflow.org/performance-rnn-browser) using tensorflow.js with my own trained midi composition.

I went through the whole python conversion process (midi -> training data -> squences ->) and endet up with a (hopefully valid)  performance_with_dynamics.mag file including my composition data.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use this dataset with the tensorflow.js library.
Could you give me a hint at which place I replace my *.mag file with the current trained model? Or did I miss some deeper understanding here?

EDIT:

I have a small update:

by runnning command line script:

" /Users/username/checkpoint_converter.py /Users/username/checkpoints/model.cpkt /Users/username/output \"

at least the script was kind of excecuted. but unfortunately it didn't accept my model.cpkt file with the following error message:

" tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /Users/chris/Desktop/AI/checkpoints/model.cpkt "

I don't know if my performance_rnn model was corrupt. Since I have three different cpkt files (index, meta & data) I don't know which is the correct cpkt file for the translation. But theres simply no documentation to find which of the training files shall be used.

maybe someone has an answer? Would helpt me hours of trial and error........

all the best christian

Comment: Tensorflow.js saved models consist of of several .json files. Did you get them?

Comment: Sebastian, thanks so much for your quick response. I'll have a look on tensorflow.js and try to convert my checkpoints into json files. I found some instruction here: https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta-js/tree/master/music ... hopefully it'll work out. This whole conversion thing feels like a huge trial and error discovery ...

Comment: Hey Sebastian, unfortuantely I didn't find out how to convert my checkpoint file into json. This whole python language is quite new to me. I'm more comfortable in the Max MSP world. 

what I try to do was the following thing:
1. create new python 3. environment.
2. pip install tensorflow 
3. pip install tensorflowjs

run terminal command:
/Users/username/checkpoints/checkpoint_converter.py \
--checkpoint_file=/Users/username/checkpoints/checkpoint.ckpt \
--output_dir=/Users/username/json \

Comment: unfortunately I terminal gives me the following error response:

"checkpoint_converter.py: error: the following arguments are required: checkpoint_file, output_dir"

maybe I just don't execute the checkpoint_converter.py properly?

all the best
c.

Comment: Sorry I never used Python as a command line interface

Comment: :) maybe I'm doing it wrong completely.

have you been able to find a workaround for converitng a magenta checkpoint file to a tensorflowjs json file without command line? 

If so I would be highly interested to be enlightened. :) 

liebe grüße
christian